# PyTorch mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am attempting to train an image classifier using PyTorch. I followed the tutorial at https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.htm, and It worked perfectly fine.

I am now trying to use a custom dataset instead of the one provided by the tutorial, and I am encountering some issues.

Here is my code for preparing the images:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Resize((224,224)),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

Here is my code for creating the data loaders:

```
trainset = datasets.ImageFolder('./Dataset/train', transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

testset = datasets.ImageFolder('./Dataset/test', transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
```

The issue appears in this class:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1) 
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

When I run my code, I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x44944 and 400x120)
```

This error did not appear when I used the dataset provided by the tutorial, even though the `Net()` class is exactly the same. The only differences between the code that did work and the code that does not work are the data loaders.

Here is the code for the original data loaders in the tutorial:

```
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data/train', train=True,
                                    download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                      shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data/test', train=False,
                                   download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                     shuffle=False, num_workers=0)
```

I have already tried many suggestions from answers to similar questions, but none of them worked. Any suggestions about what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You getting this error because you are using the model structure of one shown in the tutorial but resizing the image by `224x224`. after getting flatter it became `179776` or `4x44944`,so you have two choice either do not use `Resize` operation in `transform` here because original size of  `cifar10` is `32x32` and or if you do wanna `Resize` the image then just change your `fc1` `input dim` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Plz remove `resize` from  `transforms` since cifar10 are already 32x32x3 and no need to resize .
keep it this way, and the code will work

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToTensor(),
 transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```